# Starting a process over putty and keep it alive after session end

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, putty

I got a bitvise server installed on a windows machine to connect to the cmd via putty. Now I try to start a process remotely with start pgm.exe.

The problem: Once I close putty the process on the remote machine will exit.

On linux there is a solution with nohup or screen. Does the cmd on windows machines have something similar?

Comment: Moved here from Stack-Overflow

Answer (score -1):

Answered by eryksun on stackoverflow.com:

I did your scutwork for you. See Q185 in the Bitvise SSH server usage FAQ. They use a session Job object, which can be configured to allow breakaway. They provide a "bvrun" utility to run a process outside of the session Job. It can also run the process either attached to a new console or detached from a console, so Windows won't kill the process when the original session console is closed.